# Young boy and girl with sentient shadows in sunless world

Tags: story-identification

So, I remember reading a book series in fifth or sixth grade, and I'd love to give my nephew a copy. It was about a young boy and girl who traveled between two worlds. One world had a magical veil blocking out the sun, the other was more of a magical spirit world. They could create hard light using stones that harvested sunlight above the veil. They also had replaced their shadows with sentient cloud-beings.

I remember the girl was rather antagonistic, and not very fond of the boy, she was from more of a viking culture, and he was from more of a magician culture.

I can't for the life of me remember it unfortunately, and googling is turning up nothing.

Comment: Wasnt it so also that the boy was banished / fleeing from his home (which was in sort of a tower)?  (If so I'm thinking of the same book (and would also like to know which one it is)

Comment: It seems like it. I know the backdrop was that there was corruption in his neck of the woods. His culture was stratified by a caste system based on colors of the rainbow (ergo, Red was the bottom caste, then Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Indigo, Then violet). If I recall, he was in one of the lower castes. There were also servants who didn't fall into the caste if I remember correctly.

Comment: yepp and he was thrown into a hole from where he escaped. also they can commune with the shadows and I think the girl lived on sort of a ship didn't she? Oh and I think something had happneed to the boys father (banished/imprisoned and died or so)

Comment: If you and/or your nephew like this kind of high fantasy series, you might also like "[Five Kingdoms](https://www.goodreads.com/series/108525-five-kingdoms)" by Brandon Mull and "[The Keepers](https://www.goodreads.com/series/131538-the-keepers)" by Ted Sanders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Thomas's additional info, I was able to find it. It is Garth Nix's The Seventh Tower Series. It's a six book series, but no longer appears to be being published in the US, however it's available on Amazon pretty cheap used.

[image]

http://www.garthnix.com/books/childrens-fantasy-books/the-seventh-tower-series/

Comment: Congrats on finding this! Don't forget to come back in a couple of days and accept your own answer :-)